# Xcode FMDB to UIWebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I want to display FMDB contents  into UIWebview.

This is my code. can some one help me to how can i display in UIWebview

I want to display all loops

Thank you

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    myContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"sqlite"];

    FMDatabase *db  = [[FMDatabase alloc] initWithPath:path];

    [db open];

    FMResultSet *fResult= [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM contents"];


    while([fResult next])
    {
        edata = [fResult stringForColumn:@"title"];
        [myContent addObject:edata];
    }

    [fResult next];
    NSString *title = [fResult stringForColumn:@"title"];


    [myWeb loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@" ,@"<html><body>",title,@"</body></html>"] baseURL:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should create a `NSMutableString` and append your data to that string and load that html string in `UIWebView` like below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    myContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    NSString *path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"sqlite"];

    FMDatabase *db  = [[FMDatabase alloc] initWithPath:path];

    [db open];

    FMResultSet *fResult= [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM contents"];

    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"<html><body>"];

    while([fResult next])
    {
        [str stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p>%@</p>",[fResult stringForColumn:@"title"]]];
        edata = [fResult stringForColumn:@"title"];
        [myContent addObject:edata];
    }

    [str stringByAppendingString:@"</body></html>"];

    [fResult next];
    NSString *title = [fResult stringForColumn:@"title"];


    [myWeb loadHTMLString:str baseURL:nil];

}
```

Comment: not working , i will post my code again please help me

Comment: i solved like this: str = [str stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p>%@</p>",[fResult stringForColumn:@"title"]]];